# getting error "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established"

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to implement a very simple dialogflow agent integration with Nodejs.

However, I am facing the mentioned error: `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established.`

Below is part of my code

```js
    async function testRequest (sessionId) {
    try {

        // Create a new session
        const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
            keyFile: 'C:/...'
        });
        const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath('projectid', sessionId);
        
        // The text query request.
        const request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
              text: {
                // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
                text: 'hello',
                // The language used by the client (en-US)
                languageCode: 'en-US',
              },
            },
        };
        
          // Send request and log result
          const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
          
          logger.info('Detected intent');
          const result = responses[0].queryResult;

          if (result.intent) {
            logger.info('Intent: ');
          } else {
            logger.info('No intent matched.');
          }
        
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error('Error occurred (' + err);
    }  
}
```

Have you ever faced this error before?